# Javascript resize text as an image

Tags: javascript, image, html, resize

I was wondering how to resize a div containing some text by setting a width and height so it would stretch to fill that area like an  tag? E.g. when you set the width and height attribute of an image, it resizes the image to fill that area. I need to take an arbitrary width and height value and stretch a div containing text to those dimensions. I do not wish to send a request to a php script to build an image containing the text since it will be slow and affect the scalability of the web app. Oh, and I would preferably not like to use html5 because it is a requisite that I need compatibility with ie7+ (and firefox/chrome).

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am able to use jQuery.

Comment: U just want to stretch the text or increase the font size as well?

Comment: I want to stretch the text like an image, so if you add a width/height to the image the browser stretches the image to fill that area. I don't really care about the font size getting updated with it.

Comment: This is certainly not impossible, but will not be trivial either. Changing the font size is the only way to do this, so you will have to calculate the correct font size for a given string, and a given pixel width or height

Comment: I have already thought of such a method, but that method is unsuitable for matching both the width AND height, as the font-size increases both and I am only able to satisfy one of these variables. I was looking into vml/svg but didn't get too far.

Comment: @Andrew Jones you may want to have a look at [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) - not sure even that will help however. I'd guess that SVG (or VML for IE7) is your only hope.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here is how to do that.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Zp8AH/

However, some factors like Font Family, Division width have to be fixed, in order for this code to work.

Comment: How will `animate()` help determine the correct font size needed to fit a certain string to a specific width or height? The demo used there animates to a *font size* and a container width, but the text is not stretched to fill the container.

Comment: You have yourself given the answer to this problem in your comment `so you will have to calculate the correct font size for a given string, and a given pixel width or height`

Comment: Just to make things clearer, I need to take an arbitrary width AND height and resize the text somehow to fit the container. Setting the font size appropriately is a matter of selecting either the width OR the height, something that I cannot do.